# Linear Algebra - extracting x

Tags: linear-algebra

I need extract $X$ But fail.

I tried several methods but still could not, I would be happy help.

$$A^t(X^{-1}+A)=X^{-1}$$
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know whether $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @Mathematician42 If $A$ is singular then the LHS cannot be equal to $X^{-1}$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Well sure, but I wanted the OP to think about that.

Answer (score 1):

You have the formula of $A^T(X^{-1} + A) = X^{-1}$
By multiplying the left hand side, and using right-multiplication with $X$ you get to $A^T(I+AX)=I$.

From there on, there is some more elementary matrix-manupilation to get to something like $X= \dots$.

Be aware, that the resulting $X$ does contain inverses of $A$.